# Xamarin Android - Vulnerability testing

Tags: android, xamarin.android

i'd like to ask for suggestion. We did a vuln. testing of our mobile app written in Xamarin.Android. We used https://github.com/MobSF/Mobile-Security-Framework-MobSF

We saw there one High risk in  this item
[image]

I tried to do that D_Fortify paramater, and not sure about -fstack-protector-all.
I was checking the source code for Xamarin and they use -fstack-protector-strong.

So not quite sure, if we can do something with it, as it's Shared Library.

Thanks
Rado